# How do I align bracketed exposure panoramas in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, hdr, panorama

I bracketed 3 exposures for each part of a panorama, and then stitched 3 panoramas together, 1 at each exposure, using photoshop CC (probably called photomerge).  I now have 3 different layers with panoramas that don't quite line up (either manually or with "align layers") because of minute differences in the merging/stitching process.  Is there a way to line up on content in photoshop?

Below is a contact sheet with some of the thumbnails involved in this workflow.
[image]

Comment: related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11491/hdr-then-panorama-or-panorama-then-hdr/11497#11497

Comment: somewhat related yes, but with the essential difference that I want 3 aligned layers, not one merged HDR photograph.  I will then decide what to do with the layers afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Create an HDR first using identical settings for each shot then photomerge to create panorama.

Comment: If you take more bracketed shots, this becomes more apparent. Considering the extreme case: If you have two entirely white images or two entirely black images it is clear that they cannot be merged as a panorama. There are no distinguishing features. Those features are only visible in the exposures in between black and white. The HDR process, in a sense, synchronises the reference points for alignment throughout all exposures. Then merge the HDRs to a panorama.

Comment: Also helps to apply lens profile to the HDR's before doing photomerge especially vignetting and geometry. Some photomerge options allow to correct vignetting but you may get e better transition with the actual profile applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to approach the stitching in a different way. First you have to fuse the exposure  for each brackets and stitch the single images together.
For fusing exposure you can use some plugins like enfuse or photomatix in lightroom. The other way is to do a manual exposure blending using layer mask in Photoshop.
There are software like ptgui will do a better job in panorama creation.