# Align bracketed exposure panoramas in photoshop – Repeat script...?

Tags: photoshop, hdr, panorama, bracketing, image-alignment

I have the same question as this guy: [How do I align bracketed exposure panoramas in photoshop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69150/how-do-i-align-bracketed-exposure-panoramas-in-photoshop)

How to align bracketed exposure panoramas in Photoshop... I've tried every trick in the book, no luck. And no I do not want to blend the exposures first, before stitching my panorama. That's just not possible for this shot i'm working on.

So... that got me thinking *(and on to my question)*: after photoshop has calculated and stitched the first exposure together, shouldn't it be possible to just repeat that process with a new set of images **with the same calculations**...? I mean, shouldn't that be easy for photoshop? It just has to repeat the previous steps...

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Is there some script I could use?

(I plan to blend the HDR exposures manually in photoshop).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if Photoshop can do what you're asking, but if your actual problem is that you're trying to create an HDR panorama from a set of bracketed sets of images, I'd recommend using a different stitching tool that offers you more control.

Both [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net) and [PTGui](http://www.ptgui.com), as well as a number of other dedicated panostitching programs, can take this type of image grouping and perform both panostitching and HDR/exposure fusion at the same time. And both can also save stitch parameters from one set of images to reapply to another set.

See:

- [Hugin workflow for HDR](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/HDR_workflow_with_hugin.html)
- [Creating 360º enfused panoramas](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/enfuse-360/en.shtml)
- [HDR Panoramas with PTGui Pro](https://www.ptgui.com/hdrtutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should have mentioned: I plan to blend the HDR exposures manually in photoshop, it just gives you a lot more control. I don't think this is possible using Hugin or PTGui – or is it?

Comment: To be honest; I don’t think that Photoshop can do what i’m asking (not right now anyway – hopefully in the future…). I know the program pretty well, and if a way existed I think I would have found it by now. But I thought id check, to be sure. 

But I also thought perhaps it would be possible to achieve this by using a script…?

Comment: @Emily, you have some control, but generally with HDR, it's the tonemapping out to a viewable LDR graphic file format you need control over, and that can be done in a separate app, like Photomatix or Photoshop from the HDR file. But both Hugin and PTGui and save stitch parameters so they can be reused for different sets of files.

Comment: @Emily Because this is SE, and not a messageboard, consider [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or (when you get the rep) [upvoting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer instead of a thanks comment. Please, take [the tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) if you plan to stick around.