# What are the free HDR programs available for download?

Tags: software, hdr

Currently, I am using Photoshop Elements 9 and there are no HDR features in it (other than the Photomerge Exposure tool which can combine two pics - mini HDR function).

Photoshop CS5 is way too expensive for me and the other two possible choices are Photomatix Pro 4 and HDR Efex Pro. (which still cost close to USD $200)

I would like to ask if there are other free HDR programs available via internet download which I can use? I just want to try out the effects and see what HDR effects can do to my photographs. Can you also give me a brieft explanation of the pros and cons of the programs?

Many thanks!

Comment: Google is your friend: http://open-tube.com/free-high-dynamic-range-hdr-software

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools do you recommend for creating HDR images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/what-tools-do-you-recommend-for-creating-hdr-images)

Comment: Welcome Rick. The question I've marked as a duplicate isn't exclusively about $0-cost software, but _does_ mention that as one of the top concerns, and has some answers along those lines. Perhaps we can stir up some more activity.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Luminance HDR](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/). It's free (open source).

[This flickr group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/qtpfsgui/) can also show you some examples of HDR being used.

**PROS**

- Its Free!
- Its open source
- It works across multiple OS's

**CONS**

- Well, have not used it so cannot update this here. Others can comment and I will update as appropriate

Comment: Can you move this answer over to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/ ?

Comment: @mattdm - If you mean just add, I have done a copy and paste, if you really mean move, then I don't have the creds I believe?

Comment: Yeah that, and then delete this one if you want, as this question is likely to be closed soon. Or just leave it. Whatever. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can produce HDR images by manually blending multiple exposures in any competent image editor, such as [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/). It's more time consuming but usually produces much nicer, more tasteful and visually appealing results. See

- [How can I stop my HDR shots looking so fake?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-i-stop-my-hdr-shots-looking-so-fake)
- [How do I photograph moving subjects to allow good HDR processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/hdr-processing-on-moving-subjects)

Comment: To add to Matt's post, I've tried manual exposure blending with Paint Shop Pro (even though PSP has an HDR tool) following a Photoshop / Photoshop Elements tutorial I found some time ago (so sorry no link...) which adapted pretty well. I think I saw one on the Gimp site a while ago too. Gimp has some pretty good tutorials which you should be able to adapt readily.

Comment: In another question-answer there's example photos of exposure fusion. Might want to take a look at [How does exposure fusion work?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20897/17441)